# iOS unit tests: how to handle completion of tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xctest

I want to write path of test artifacts at the end of output in console. It would be handy. And I'm also just curious.

It seems that XCTest somehow terminate the app, app delegate doesn't receive lifecycle callbacks, program exits before main function from main.m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Test Execution and Observation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/test_execution_and_observation) specifically [testBundleDidFinish](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestobservation/1500819-testbundledidfinish).

If you define an object which adopts `XCTestObservation` you can add it to the `XCTestObservationCenter.shared` instance at any point during your test suite's run and receive a call when the entire bundle has finished.

Answer (score 3):

Jonah helped me, I also want to place some code here for other people.

To start observation before any test there is a proper way to do it.
There is `NSPrincipalClass` key in test bundle's Info.plist. Put there a name of your "principal class" (google it for more info). In my case it is `PrincipalClass`. When test bundle is loaded, `init` is called in the principal class. Here's my `PrincipalClass`:

```
@objc(PrincipalClass)
final class PrincipalClass: NSObject {
    override init() {
        TestObservationEntryPoint.instance.startObservation()
    }
}
```

I was able to make cool reporting system with Allure2. Reporting is not what I wanted at the time I asked this question, but it was possible because I found an answer. It is a good application of test observation in XCTest.

Answer (score 1):

For me the answers were very confusing.

```
func testYourTest() {
 let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "Your action")

 API.sharedInstance.yourRequestWithCompletionAndFailure(parameter: parameter, completion: { (response) in

 //XCTAssert with response

 expectation.fulfill()
 }) { (error) in
  //XCTAssert with your error
 expectation.fulfill()
 }

 wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 30.0)
}
```

With expectation you listen to a response. Don't forget to set a timeout. 
More Details/Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations